# How to count related id on second table quicker in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I need to know how many orders made to each product within a day by their ids. I tried select all the `product_today.id`. And count each of them from the second table - `product_today_order.hid`. I'm now have 20k+ rows of data. It took me 10s+ only this query.

Is there any way to make the query faster?

```
SELECT t.id,(select count(o.hid) from product_today_order o where o.hid=t.id) as zid 
FROM product_today t
where date(t.dtime)='2021-11-26'
group by t.id
```

Comment: show a create table from both and an expalin and try to join  and not to subselect

Comment: 20K rows in which table?  How many in the other table?

Answer (score 1):

5 tips:

- Probably the main slowdown is the un-sargable `date(t.dtime)='...'`.  Change that to

  ```
    WHERE t.dtime >= '2021-11-26'
      AND t.dtime  < '2021-11-26' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ```
- Also, get rid of the `GROUP BY`.  It is unnecessary (if `t.id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`).
- Do you have an index on `t` that *starts with* `dtime`?
- Do you need to check `o.hid` for being not-NULL?  If not, simply say `COUNT(*)`.
- Do you have an index on `o` that *starts with* `hid`?

Comment: I changed the `where t.dtime` to your suggestion but no faster.
I removed `group by` but it's only display where `product_today_order` existed.
I have index on `t` that starts with `dtime`.
I changed the query to `COUNT(*)`.
I have an index on `o` that starts with `hid`.

This is the updated version.

`SELECT t.id,(select count(*) from product_today_order o where o.hid=t.id) as zid 
FROM product_today t
WHERE t.dtime >= '2021-11-26'
    AND t.dtime  < '2021-11-26' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
group by t.id`